# How do I only allow certain commands to be run in my shell?

Tags: linux, shell

Im currently writing my own shell in C. It isn't anything big. It's only has a few built-in commands like one of my commands is `ifc` and would do the same thing as the `ifconfig` command on a normal shell. But I want to restrict my shell from being able to call other commands that are not specified in my shell.

For example. I made the `ifc` command to replace `ifconfig` but `ifconfig` is still callable from  my shell even though it isn't build in.

Is this possible to do and how would it be done?

Comment: Make an array of strings that contains all of the allowed commands. If the user-supplied command isn't found in that array, then reject the command.

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah ok that will work but is there any other way?

Comment: Not sure what you have in mind. You either need a list of acceptable commands, or a list of unacceptable commands, or a list of aliased commands.

Comment: A popular way of implementing restricted shell environments is to have a directory full of symlinks to permitted commands and force the shell to search only that directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. The most simple way - just allow certain commands in your shell.
2. You can build shared library and with LD_PRELOAD, attach it to your shell,
   this library catches all calls like execl and allow/disallow it based on you rules. Like firewall, but for calling programs.
3. Another way is to modify Linux kernel that checks if current process is your shell, then do not exec something.
4. You can write policy for your shell SELinux or AppArmor to do things like (2)